# How to add blank lines above the bottom in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ubuntu, terminal

In vim and many other text editors, you can scroll up the end of the file to the top of your screen while showing the rest of the lines as blank. But in terminal, by default, the end of line is fixed to the end of the terminal screen so your current line is always appearing at the bottom. How can I scroll up the current line while adding blank lines between the last line and the bottom of screen?
Thanks.

Comment: I've installed screen and tmux

Answer (score 2):

Most terminals recognize VT100-style *scrolling regions*.  You can use those to temporarily set limits on the lines which would be scrolled, and move the lines.

Step-by-step:

- save the current cursor position
- find the number of lines on the screen
- compute the last line-number (above) which you want to leave as-is
- write the control sequence for setting the scrolling margins just past that line, through the end of the screen
- move the cursor to the last line (of the screen and the scrolling region)
- send control sequence (or line-feeds, etc), to force the scrolling region to "index" upward
- unset the scrolling margins
- restore the cursor position

In a script, you can do most of this with `tput`, e.g.,

- `tput sc` to save the cursor position
- `tput csr` *first last*, to set the scrolling regions to the first/last lines
- `tput cup` *last 0*, to move the cursor to the last line in the scrolling region (using the same *last* value as in the `csr` command)
- `tput ind` to index-up once, or `tput indn`*count*, to index up by *count* lines.
- `tput rc` to restore the cursor position

The commands (`csr`, etc.) are *terminal capabilities* and **can** differ from one terminal to another.

Though widely used, *scrolling regions* are not in the standard ([ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)).

Further reading:

- [**`tput`**,  **`reset`**  -  initialize  a  terminal or query terminfo database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html)
- [terminfo - terminal capability data base](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Shift and page up and down.
If you're on Mac, fn + shift + up or down